# How can find the center point of svg bezier path in android

Tags: android, svg, android-canvas

I have convert svg path to bezier path by svgparser.
I have a text file in which we have all the world country svg path. I have draw all bezier path but now how I can get centre of each bezier curve.

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.Path;
    import android.graphics.RectF;
    import android.graphics.Region;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;


    public class RegionViewClass extends MapView implements View.OnTouchListener {
        Path mPath;
        Paint mPaint;
        Region mRegion;
        Context mContext;
        MapView mapView;
        int p,q;
```

This is the svg path of 3 countries. how I can differentiate every path on touch Event.

```
        String d = "M670.98,313.01l4.58-2.24l2.72-9.84l-0.12-12.08l15.58-16.82v-3.99l3.21-1.25l-0.12-4.61l-3.46-6.73l1.98-3.61l4.33,3.99l5.56,0.25v2.24l-1.73,1.87l0.37,1l2.97,0.12l0.62,3.36h0.87l2.23-3.99l1.11-10.46l3.71-2.62l0.12-3.61l-1.48-2.87l-2.35-0.12l-9.2,6.08l0.58,3.91l-6.46-0.02l-2.28-2.79l-1.24,0.16l0.42,3.88l-13.97-1l-8.66-3.86l-0.46-4.75l-5.77-3.58l-0.07-7.37l-3.96-4.53l-9.1,0.87l0.99,3.96l4.46,3.61l-7.71,15.78l-5.16,0.39l-0.85,1.9l5.08,4.7l-0.25,4.75l-5.19-0.08l-0.56,2.36l4.31-0.19l0.12,1.87l-3.09,1.62l1.98,3.74l3.83,1.25l2.35-1.74l1.11-3.11l1.36-0.62l1.61,1.62l-0.49,3.99l-1.11,1.87l0.25,3.24L670.98,313.01L670.98,313.01z" +
            "M671.19,242.56l0.46,4.27l8.08,3.66l12.95,0.96l-0.49-3.13l-8.65-2.38l-7.34-4.37L671.19,242.56L671.19,242.56z\n" +
            "M695.4,248.08l1.55,2.12l5.24,0.04l-0.53-2.9L695.4,248.08L695.4,248.08z\n"+"M781.68,324.4l-2.31,8.68l-12.53,4.23l-3.75-4.4l-1.82,0.5l3.4,13.12l5.09,0.57l6.79,2.57v2.57l3.11-0.57l4.53-6.27v-5.13l2.55-5.13l2.83,0.57l-3.4-7.13l-0.52-4.59L781.68,324.4L781.68,324.4z\n"+
            "M473.88,227.49l-4.08-1.37l-16.98,3.19l-3.7,2.81l2.26,11.67l-6.75,0.27l-4.06,6.53l-9.67,2.32l0.03,4.75l31.85,24.35l5.43,0.46l18.11-14.15l-1.81-2.28l-3.4-0.46l-2.04-3.42v-14.15l-1.36-1.37l0.23-3.65l-3.62-3.65l-0.45-3.88l1.58-1.14l-0.68-4.11L473.88,227.49L473.88,227.49z\n";
    ;

        public RegionViewClass(Context context) {
            super(context);
            this.mContext=context;
            mPath = new Path();
            mRegion=new Region();
            mPath= SVGParser.parsePath(d);
            setFocusable(true);
            setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            this.setOnTouchListener(this);
            mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(20);
            RectF rectF = new RectF();
            mPath.computeBounds(rectF, true);
            mRegion.setPath(mPath, new Region((int) rectF.left, (int) rectF.top, (int) rectF.right, (int) rectF.bottom));
        }
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            //canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

        }


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Point point = new Point();
            point.x=event.getX();
            point.y = event.getY();
            invalidate();

            if(mRegion.contains((int) point.x,(int) point.y)==true)
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "inside", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Path selectedPath=  mRegion.getBoundaryPath();
            if (mPath==selectedPath){
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "india", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("", "" + selectedPath);

            }

            else
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "outside", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return true;

        }

       /* private boolean contains(int i, int j) {
        }*/

        class Point {
            float x, y;

            @Override
            public String toString() {

                return x + ", " + y;
            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test which of the sub-paths in your path the user clicks on.  You will need to separate them into separate path definitions.  Then run the Region.contains() test on each of them individually.

Comment: ok.. thanks for showing intrest.Can you please tell me how we can get the center point of each separate path?

Comment: Actually i want to draw a bitmap at the centre of every path ,if i will do  by every region of path then it'll be the outside of path draw     Rect rect=mRegion[i].getBounds();
                        rect_x=rect.centerX();There is any method so i can get the centre co ordinate of path .
                         rect_y=rect.centerY();

Comment: I am still confused.  It is still not clear to me what you want.  Could you update your question with the new information you have put here.  And perhaps you could add an image showing what you want.  When you say "centre of path", do you mean "a point that is inside the shape and roughly at the centre of the shape"?

Answer (score 0):

Your given paths don't have bezier curves. And shouldn't as counties don't tend to define curved boundaries with each other (save a couple examples where we use longitude like the US Canada border has a curve, because Earth is curved).

But, if you want. The formula to calculate the centermost point in a bezier curve, is:

```
t = 0.5;
x = (1 - t) * (1 - t) * p[0].x + 2 * (1 - t) * t * p[1].x + t * t * p[2].x;
y = (1 - t) * (1 - t) * p[0].y + 2 * (1 - t) * t * p[1].y + t * t * p[2].y;
```

Which answers your first question. The answer to the proper question, how can you tell which touch is part of which path is a harder one, and given that you actually have a polygon the correct answer is to implement a path in polygon algorithm.

But, really what you want is something that works. Might I recommend a handle. Simply draw something at the center of the shape for each regional shape. Then when the person touches the screen, find the closest point, to that point. Most countries are vaguely roundish or typically not weirdly curved, so simply find the bounding region then do distance to the center point.

Divide up the paths for each country. Get a bounding box for the county. Check whether that touch is inside any bounding box. If it is, compare the closeness of that touch to the center of that bounding box for all countries whose hit box was hit by that touch.